# How to get Controller response in HandlerInterceptor Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to read the object returned by the controller in the function postHandle of a HandlerInterceptor.

**Interceptor**

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, 
        Object handler, ModelAndView model)  throws Exception {
        // Read Object here
    }
}
```

**The RestController**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public Object testingTest() {
        TestModel test = new TestModel();
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is rather already written to the response output stream. It might be available in `model`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813457/how-to-get-returned-value-of-my-controllers-from-handlerinterceptor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get returned value of my controllers from HandlerInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813457/how-to-get-returned-value-of-my-controllers-from-handlerinterceptor)